# base64_decode HTML5 canvas, returning null

Tags: php

I have a canvas image i want to upload via AJAX, but when i base64_decode the

```
$dataUrl = $data['dataUrl'];
$parts = explode(',', $dataUrl);
$img_data = $parts[1];
$img_data = str_replace(' ','+',$img_data);
$img_data = base64_decode($img_data);
// Save data as an image
$fp = fopen('image.png', 'w');  
fwrite($fp, $img_data);  
fclose($fp); 
die();
```

If i echo img data, it is null, but i do get an invalid image produced, the image has a size of 7-8kB but it is corrupted.

The data sendt to the server:

```
 data[dataUrl]:data:image/png;base64,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
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: Why `str_replace(' ','+',$img_data)`? Also consider [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure your not allowed to replace all spaces by '+'! And I also think (depending on your config) you might use stripslashes() on your "get" or "post" data. Also a explode() is the wrong way to cut a string in two parts :-)

My example code would by something like this:

```
$dataUrl = $data['dataUrl'];

$dataUrl = stripslashes($dataUrl); //-- not sure!

$pos = strpos($dataUrl, ',');
if ($pos<0) return;
$base_data = substr($dataUrl, $pos+1);

$img_data = base64_decode($base_data);
```